# Present UIAlertViewController from ChildViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, parent-child

As an attempt to reduce the code in my main view controller, I refactor most functions to two child view controller.

In one of the child view controller, users can tap on a button which triggered an ActionSheet. My first attempt to complete this action is to

1. Two child view controllers are connected to the parent view controller in storyboard
2. Create delegate property in child view controller 1.
3. In prepareForSegue of parent view controller, check segue.identifier match the one to child view controller, then assign parent view controller as delegate of child view controller
4. Conform parent view controller to protocol which has a method that accept a view controller as parameter
5. When user tap on the button in child view controller 1, the delegate function is called which pass in the child view controller 1 to the delegate function and raise the action sheet in parent view controller
6. Once users made the action, the property of the child view controller is updated

When I tried to run, I get the following error: `Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f9bb6029200> on <BudgetSmart.TransactionListViewController: 0x7f9bb5d298b0> while a presentation is in progress!`

I tried to 1. dismiss view controller, 2. call the action sheet from child view controller but the error persist. Is the view controller in presentation referring to the child view controller? If so what should be the approach to resolve this? Thank you!

Comment: I have seen this error before, though it rarely pops up for me. Can you provide some code of how you are doing this?

Comment: Open storyboard on the particular view controller on which you are presenting alert controller in attribute inspector change presentation style to full screen it's quick fix i will add answer as well in a while with proper implementation.

Comment: I added more details in my setup. Making the view controller presentation style full screen result in the same error

Answer (score 0):

How is your child view controller shown? Is it presented by the parent by calling presentViewController? If so, then when you present the action sheet by the parent, you will see that error message, because parent has already presented child. You need to present the child view controller in full screen and present the action sheet from child.

Comment: The 2 child view controllers are added to the parent view controllers on the storyboard. I have 2 child view controllers, changing both to full screen did not work. My hypothesis is also that the problem is cause by child view controller being presented. However calling dismiss did not help. I will attempt to overlay the parent view controller instead. Appreciate any suggestions too